# PostgreSQL Allow Connections From a MAC Address

Tags: configuration, configure, mac-address, postgresql-9.1

Is there a configuration directive in PostgreSQL 9.1 to allow connections from a client by writing its MAC address instead of writing its IP address into 'pg_hba.conf'?

For instance; instead of doing this;

```
host    all             all             192.168.2.1/32           trust
```

I'd like to write this;

```
host    all             all             00:08:C7:1B:8C:02        trust
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

As [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) say:

> This field can contain either a host name, an IP address range, or one
>   of the special key words mentioned below.